# Java object scope between methods

Tags: java, object, methods

I'm having issues with this code running, I'm trying to get the program to print the strings below by using input from the other classes. As you can see, the info put into the new Bride and Location objects are being put in to a Wedding Object and then I need to try and retrieve the details from the wedding object and display it on screen like so:

> Wedding data:
>   Bride: Amy Cronos, age: 29
>   Location: South Rd, suburb: Tonsley

but I am instead met with 4 identical errors relating to the place.getName, place.getSuburb() etc. etc. that say

> Main.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
>   System.out.println("Location"+place.getStreet()+", suburb:
>   "+place.getsuburb());
>
> symbol:   variable place
>
> location: class Main

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the scope, but cant work out what I need to do.

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Here is the code:

```
public class WeddingDetails {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Bride person = new Bride("Amy Cronos", 29);
        Location place = new Location("Tonsley", "South Rd");
        Wedding wed = new Wedding(person, place);
        show(wed);
    }

    public static void show(Wedding wed) {
        System.out.println("Wedding data:");
        System.out.println("Bride: " + person.getName() + ", age: " + person.getAge());
        System.out.println("Location: " + place.getStreet() + ", suburb: " + place.getSuburb());

    }

    public static class Location {

        private String suburb;
        private String street;

        Location(String suburb, String street) {
            this.suburb = suburb;
            this.street = street;
        }

        public String getSuburb() {
            return suburb;
        }

        public String getStreet() {
            return street;
        }
    }

    public static class Bride {

        private String name;
        private int age;

        Bride(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

    }

    public static class Wedding {

        private Bride person;
        private Location place;

        Wedding(Bride person, Location place) {
            this.person = person;
            this.place = place;

        }

        public Bride getBride() {
            return person;
        }

        public Location getPlace() {
            return place;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately there are several problems with your question: the title has nothing to do with the question; it's unclear what your question really is; you have a basic syntax error that isn't appropriate content for SO. I suggest you delete the question, read the documentation on how to ask a question and try again.

Comment: you're trying to access `person` in your show() method and its declared in main.  Try getting the `Bride` from `wed` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is your println statements are trying to access methods within objects, but by calling those methods on the wrong object.  You should be accessing the Bride and Location objects with the Wedding class' getters (getBride() and getPlace().  The complete call would be wed.getBride().getName() and wed.getPlace().getStreet() so on.

Corrected code is below.  NOTE: for the purposes of being able to compile all of the code inside one class, I added the `static` keyword to the Bride, Location and Wedding class declarations.  You can just remove the `static` and copy and paste each class back into your .java files.

```
public class WeddingDetails {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Bride person = new Bride("Amy Cronos", 29);
        Location place = new Location("Tonsley", "South Rd");
        Wedding wed = new Wedding(person, place);
        show(wed);
    }

    public static void show(Wedding wed) {
        System.out.println("Wedding data:");
        System.out.println("Bride: " + wed.getBride().getName() + ", age: " + wed.getBride().getAge());
        System.out.println("Location: " + wed.getPlace().getStreet() + ", suburb: " + wed.getPlace().getSuburb());

    }

    public static class Location {

        private String suburb;
        private String street;

        Location(String suburb, String street) {
            this.suburb = suburb;
            this.street = street;
        }

        public String getSuburb() {
            return suburb;
        }

        public String getStreet() {
            return street;
        }
    }

    public static class Bride {

        private String name;
        private int age;

        Bride(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

    }

    public static class Wedding {

        private Bride person;
        private Location place;

        Wedding(Bride person, Location place) {
            this.person = person;
            this.place = place;

        }

        public Bride getBride() {
            return person;
        }

        public Location getPlace() {
            return place;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Brooks, that was the issue, champion!